# Need to get input text with javascript then add it to a sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I need so far.  I need to have the quantity input box's value to be added to a sentence after the input area.

Right now I have this code for the input for quantity:

```
 <label for="quantity">Qty: </label> 
 <input min="1" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" onkeyup="getVals(this, 'text');"  />
 <input type="submit" id="add-to-cart" class="btn addtocart" name="add" value="Add to cart" />
 <div class="how-many">You have helped save <span id="pTextInput"></span>people</div>
```

I would like the input value for id quantity to be inserted into the span id="pTextInput".

So basically if the quantity input is set to 2 then the sentence, You have helped save 2 people would show up (the dynamic number being placed in the span.

Hope this makes sense. I can use regular javascript or jquery, whichever is easiest.

Comment: Do you have a question? This isn't a McDonald's drive-through.

Comment: The question is in there. I tried to explain it more with an example of how i want this to work

Comment: A list of requirements for your idea isn't a question. You should show what you've written so far and describe where specifically you're stuck. Otherwise you're treating StackOverflow like a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you might be looking for something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#pTextInput").html("1"); 
    $("#quantity").on("change keyup", function() {
      $("#pTextInput").html($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>

 <label for="quantity">Qty: </label> 
 <input min="1" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
 <input type="submit" id="add-to-cart" class="btn addtocart" name="add" value="Add to cart" />
 <div class="how-many">You have helped save <span id="pTextInput"></span> people</div>
```

As you change the input of `quantity`, the `pTextInput` value will change with it.

Comment: That works perfectly except that the default value of 1 does not show up until you change the quantity up or down.  I would need this to have the value of 1 if the quantity is not changed (default value is 1).

Comment: Updated my answer to get "1" to show up by default. If this works well, please accept :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
function getVals(input) {
    document.getElementById("pTextInput").innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

Also, change getVals(this, 'text') to getVals(this) - no need for 'text'.

I would suggest taking a look at DOM manipulation basics with JS: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: I tried this approach but it did not work. No errors, but no dynamic number shows up.